# USB IC from Cypress does not let me charge devices with power adapters with unconnected data pins

Tags: usb-device

I have a product using the Cypress CY7C65213 USB-UART bridge controller. We started to face some field problems where the clients reported that the device was not charging with some power adaptors. I check it and the problem occurs when the power adapters have unconencted data pins. The USB seems to enter suspend mode in these cases. I have tested some changes on the USB BCD table to check what was happening and this new configuration (in the image) seems to work.

[image]

Basically, I have increased the SDP current to 500mA (previous 100mA), and swapped lines for configured SDP and USB suspend. I have tested with power adapters with unconnected data pins and shorted data pins. It worked well: With shorted pins, the maximum current is  800mA and with open pins 500mA.

I am afraid to have field problems that I am not seeing. Any tips to reproduce the USB suspend state on an USB host and check what will happen?

Comment: Please show the relevant part of the circuit as well - where the power is handled

Comment: [What is the USB suspend mode?](https://honeywellaidc.force.com/supportppr/s/article/What-is-the-USB-suspend-mode) says that USB suspend mode is activated on a compliant device when there is no bus traffic for 3 milliseconds. Therefore, this charger is indeed activating USB suspend mode, because it is wrongly designed. Perhaps you may decide that your device will also ignore USB suspend mode (making it noncompliant as well?).

Comment: @user253751 thanks, you have opened my mind. If the Ps has data pins opened, the USB must enter suspend mode cause no data arrives on the bus. Probably mobile suppliers are noncompliant with this standard, cause you can use these NC Ps to charge cellphones easily. Probably I will not use suspend mode

Comment: D+ and D- aren't shorted to each other in these chargers, right? That indicates a "Dedicated Charging Port". They are completely disconnected?

Comment: Yes, completely disconnected. I have seen this type of charger before, the majority come from China and are very cheap. Short circuit the USB works normal as a DCP

Comment: well, you could make your device draw high current in suspend mode, but it's not strictly *allowed* to do that and maybe it will drain someone's laptop battery. Another idea is to give the affected customers some adapters that short the D+ and D- pins, and tell them to superglue them in the faulty chargers? heh, but maybe there's a liability problem there (I am not a lawyer).

Comment: I think your question was just how to reproduce USB suspend state, though, so why not just cut the data lines in a scrap USB cable?

Comment: After your comments I figured out that indeed I was reproducing it already with a NC power source. Now I know what to do (perphaps hehe) thank you!